# Can I get a local sim card at London Ontario International Airport (YXU)?

Tags: canada, airports, cellphones, ontario

I'll be arriving at London Ontario International Airport at night about 9pm next week. I was wondering if I could get a local sim card with a data plan at the airport then? How much would it cost and what are your recommendations?

Thanks.

Maz

Comment: YXU hasn't got many international flights, so are you connecting at another airport in Canada?  You might have better luck buying a sim card there.

Comment: Hi Nate! I'll be transiting at Toronto's airport. What kind of prepaid card do you recommend?

Comment: I don't have any recommendations, sorry.  I don't live in Canada and am not familiar with what's available, nor do I know what your needs might be.  But I am pretty sure you could find something airside in Toronto, probably with more choices than a 24-hour convenience store (though maybe also more expensive).

Answer (score 1):

For the plan that best suits you, the [prepaid with data wiki](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Canada) is always a good bet. YXU is a pretty small airport so I don't think it has anywhere to buy a SIM. However, Google Maps shows a [7-11 a short distance away](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/London+International+Airport/7-Eleven,+1579+Oxford+St+E,+London,+ON+N5V+1W5,+Canada/@43.0174392,-81.1825764,14.13z/am=t/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0x6b27b8df4b0ba78f!2m2!1d-81.1495664!2d43.0332955!1m5!1m1!1s0x882eed0d15b0f1ad:0x7848d885bc51b3c1!2m2!1d-81.1985131!2d43.0111081) that is open 24 hours. They should have a variety of SIMs there.

Comment: 7-11 has a shit selection of SIMs, I think Speakout only.